# How to horizontally align side by side divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 divs that need to be displayed side-by-side and evenly distributed within the parent div width (which is set to 100% of the window). Whats the best way of doing it?

See example below which is just floating the 3 divs (which just places them one after the other to the left, not what I need).

PS: the list of options is dynamic, i.e. I might have more than 3 divs so the solution should ideally take that into account. Thanks! :)

PS 2: I am using bootstrap so if there is a good way of doing this using bootstrap I'm all for it.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.option {
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="option">
        Box A
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        Box B
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        Box C
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: **100% / 3 box = 33%** ... CSS -> option add `width: 33%` .. basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lddyn573/5/

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.option {
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Now would it be possible to perhaps make so Box A starts at the very left side (with perhaps just a little padding), Box B in the middle and Box C on the far right (again, with a little padding)? In other words, would it be possible to control/increase the spacing between the elements?

Comment: If using bootstrap, one should avoid that kind of custom CSS imho. That`s what bootstrap was made for...

Comment: @wdanda yes you can use `space-between` instead, I added 10px of padding for the example https://jsfiddle.net/Lddyn573/6/

Answer (score 1):

Just use flexbox compliments of CSS3. The beauty of it is that so long as there is enough space in the parent element you can add additional children and they will automatically display next to each other. Be mindful that once the parent runs out of space additional child elements will need resize themselves so that they display next to each other. See the below example from W3schools:

```css
 .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Bootstrap [Grid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

```css
.option {
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
}
```

```html
<?php
// whatever $items contains...
$items = [];

$columnWidth = floor(12 / count($items)) ?: 1;
?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="option col-md-<?php echo $columnWidth;?>">
        Box A
    </div>
    <div class="option col-md-<?php echo $columnWidth;?>">
        Box B
    </div>
    <div class="option col-md-<?php echo $columnWidth;?>">
        Box C
    </div>

</div>
```

The `.row` CSS should not be needed if you include bootstrap css.

However, that `$columnWidth` calculation will only work for a maximum of 12 items (that is the maximum number of columns, bootstrap supports per row) and will only result in full-width rows if the number of items is a divisor of 12 (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12).

Comment: my problem with this is that i might have 4, or 5 or even 6 columns, and they have to display on the same row (i.e. cannot break). so that means i'd have to know the count and then adjust the -4 (which works for 3 elements) into something else (i.e. -3 for 4 elements, etc)

Comment: You could use php to calculate the column-size. I`ll add an example.